# How to remove VB6 app dependency on msvbvm50.dll?

Tags: vb6, dependencies, vb5

I upgraded a `VB5` project by opening it in the `VB6` IDE and then compiling.

The generated `.EXE` does not work without `msvbvm50.dll` being present.

How can I remove the dependency of `msvbvm50.dll` from the `VB6` project?

Comment: Does it use any other components that could require msvbvm50.dll ? Is it still listed in the project's references?

Comment: @CJ7 - You need to do more than say "does not work without msvbvm50.dll" being present. What is the error? Does it happen when executing code inside the EXE, or does it happen when executing code in a OCX or DLL? Try to break it down exactly where the error is occurring. It's tedious, I know, but persistence is required for this job.